# ThreeJS - Render certain meshes from GLTF file into RenderTarget

Tags: three.js

I have a GLTF file that contains a number of meshes, i want to target a few and render them into a renderTarget texture while keeping them in my scene, as per the image below.

Can i achieve without duplicating meshes and adding them to a separate renderTarget scene?

Maybe by setting stencil buffer properties on the target meshes;

```
group.traverse((child) => {
  const stencil = ['knife', 'sword'].includes(child.name)

  if (stencil) {
    child.material.stencilWrite = true
    child.material.stencilRef = 1
  }
  child.material.needsUpdate = true
})
```

Then rendering the stencilBuffers into the renderTexture on frame update?

```
// enable stencil 
renderer.setRenderTarget(renderTarget)
renderer.render(scene, camera)
// disable stencil

renderer.setRenderTarget(null)
renderer.render(scene, camera)
```

Heres my attempt drawing a cone onto a plane, then rendering the plane into the a rendertexture. https://codepen.io/camoconnell/pen/yLrJQMP

I've struggled to find examples of this, any help appreciated.
Thanks

EDIT : New approach (Thanks @VítZadina !) using layers - https://codepen.io/camoconnell/pen/bGJwNrM

[image]

Comment: Maybe just use layers - https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Layers. And two cameras? You can set up for some objects layers which will be rendered only with second camera. After this i think it's possible to render camera to diffrent render target.

Comment: Thanks @VítZadina! i will give this a go today and update the question with my results. Cheers

Comment: If you will feel stuck on something just ask here. I will try help you with some problems. Also I think you can set layers to renderers, but I am not sure with this one. I know there was some bugs in order version.

Comment: Awesome, layers has me heading in the right direction, have updated question with solution. Thanks again @VítZadina